# How to arrange html files in phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I have just moved from iOS/Android dev to phonegap. In my phonegap project, all files are in www folder. I have several html files under that folder mixed with other folders/files, Xcode arrange them in alphabetical order and this makes it difficult to find the html file I want to edit.

So I have tried to create a html folder. However, by doing this, phonegap will no longer take my modifications in html files into account.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your index.html in the www root folder and move all the other files in to your HTML folder. And refer other html files using relative links. This way PhoneGap will load your index.html and then navigation will be easy to other files from index.html.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Another question, when showing the splash image, it seems my app is showing 2 images sequentially. Any idea?